# implementing a component for Click+Drag

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to implement this component in React
[image: reveal image]
in the link below
http://uxkids.com/portfolio/the-new-apprentice-software-for-treasury/

How is drag + click implemented, and how do you unmask part of the image? There are 2 images underneath

```
<div className="parent">
   <div className="dragControl" id="bar"></div>
   <img src="image1.jpg" />
   <img src="image2.jpg" />
</div>
```

How do you create that mask in order unmask the 2 images? They look like both are position absolute and then slowly unmasked.

I just wanted to know the HTML/CSS part, since this is giving me a mental block from able to implement the React code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I once had to do a similar effect with just jQuery and plain HTML. Here's a recreation I threw together on [codepen](https://codepen.io/pizzacops/pen/ZEWgoPw).

The trick to the effect is having two absolutely positioned images in a parent container, with a click-event on the parent. Inside the click-event, you need to get the value of the mouse position. Position the slider-handle to the mouse x-coordinate, and then the width of the top image needs to be the width of the mouse x-coordinate minus the left offset of the parent:

```
 var offset = container.offset().left;
 var x = e.clientX - offset;
```

Then giving the top image an `overflow: hidden` value will create the effect of covering and uncovering the bottom image as the width of the image wrapper-container changes.

The main problem I came up against was that trying to dynamically resize an img tag didn't work. Thus the solution was to wrap each image in its own container.

You also need to add this condition to the event listener to check if the mouse x-coordinate is within the parent container, otherwise, the slider handle will slide outside of the image:

```
   if (x < 700 && x > 0) {
    // change css here
   }
```

another thing to mention, I added these css values to the image wrappers:

```
pointer-events: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
```

This will stop the browser from creating a flickering blue rectangle as the mouse clicks and drags on the image to drag it across the screen.

I hope this alleviates your issue or at least sets you on the right path. Happy Halloween!